# VB 2015: Calculating based on form state, no variables

Tags: vb.net, winforms

My current VB homework requires us to build a simple form (in Visual Studio 2015) for rent calculation at a hotel. The user types a numeric value into a text box, and then based on other factors that are or are not present, the actual rent is displayed in a label when they click a button on the form to execute. The controls on the form are text boxes or comboboxes for user input and they affect the rate. For example, the user might type 300 in for the base rent, but if they also have the "breakfast" box checked, they pay 15 more per night, so a rent value of 315 would be displayed in the output label when they click to execute.

The complication is that we can't use any variables. We can only use the values present in the form when the user clicks execute to determine the final value displayed in the label. So how do I tie the clicking of the button to a command that says "look at all these checkboxes and comboboxes and use them to modify a value in a text box" without using variables?

I tried using if statements but that just made the number go up every time I clicked anything. How do I make the code only look at the exact state the form is in when a button is clicked, and then use that form state to modify an already-entered value from the user?

As requested, here is my code, but my professor said it was all wrong and to completely rethink it and start over.

```
Public Class frmJMtest_hl
    Private Sub btnCalcRent_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalcRent.Click
        If cboBuilding.Text = "High End" Then txtRent.Text = txtRent.Text + 210
        If chkBreakfast.Checked = True Then txtRent.Text = txtRent.Text + 65
        If chkBalcony.Checked = True Then txtRent.Text = txtRent.Text + 120
        If chkNoSmoking.Checked = True Then txtRent.Text = txtRent.Text - 15
        lblResults.Text = txtRent.Text
End Class
```

Comment: You really need to show us the code you have tried, rather than describing it. That way, people have a chance of correcting your errors.

Comment: On the one hand, since a textbox can only store text, not a number, it means you will have more complex expression to convert from text to numeric if you cant use vars.  On the other, whats the problem?  If the user types `300` in a textbox, its there no matter where your code is

Comment: Do you have an event handler attached to the `Button`'s `Click` event?  That would be the place to perform your computation based on the state of the form's controls.  As for how to preserve the value the user enters for the rate without using a variable, can you just use a separate, read-only text box to display the final calculated value?

Comment: Code added above, sorry for the oversight, since my professor said it was all wrong I didn't think it would help.

Comment: Put `Option Strict On` at the top of your code file and you will see that the code will not compile.

Comment: Your teacher shouldn't be showing you this way of calculating. Ask him what happens when you try adding two numbers taken from TextBoxes. E.g. Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text  + TextBox2.Text. Bad bad bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of modifying `txtRent` based on the various conditions and then copying that value to `lblResults`, copy the value to `lblResults` *first* and then modify `lblResults` according to those conditions:

```
Private Sub btnCalcRent_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalcRent.Click
    lblResults.Text = txtRent.Text
    If cboBuilding.Text = "High End" Then lblResults.Text = lblResults.Text + 210
    If chkBreakfast.Checked = True Then lblResults.Text = lblResults.Text + 65
    If chkBalcony.Checked = True Then lblResults.Text = lblResults.Text + 120
    If chkNoSmoking.Checked = True Then lblResults.Text = lblResults.Text - 15
End Sub
```

`txtRent` is never modified and, therefore, keeps the value entered by the user.

(If this were C# there'd be some casting to and from integers required, and I'm not sure if the above will work in VB.NET, but this is just a reworking of the code provided.)

Comment: Thank you SO much, BACON! This appears to have resolved my issue. I feel really dumb for not realizing this, but I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @Sinistar Please accept this answer with the check mark (tick Mark) to the left of the answer. This is the best way to thank the poster on SO.